# Stop IDE from referencing Sass variables not in current scope

Tags: webpack, sass, phpstorm

I am hoping that there is actually possible.

The scenario is quite simple but I cannot find a solution.

So I am developing an app and that app is essentially going to be split into 2 micro apps - a frontend and a backend (admin panel). There is complete or almost complete separation of concerns between the 2 apps, save for the fact that both belong to the same website.

So, to give an example, my root folder structure looks like this: -

```
\src\frontend
    \backend
```

So both the frontend and backend exist under the same root `\src` directory. Inside, each of the micro apps have their own Bootstrap/Sass system in place.

What is driving me crazy is that PhpStorm as the IDE is including the Sass variables (and everything else for that matter) for both micro apps when I am developing. So, for instance, when I am developing in the frontend app, my Sass setup can use variables from the backend directory. This defeats the separation of concerns and it making things very messy.

I came across PhpStorm scopes and I thought that might solve the issue. I set up and used a scope called Frontend, making sure I excluded from that scope the entire backend folder structure. Yet still I can see and use the backend's Sass variables when developing my frontend app. This is extremely annoying to say the least.

Does anyone know of a way to stop this from happening?

BTW, if it is of any importance, I am using webpack and the apps are being built in ReactJS.

#### Edit:

I am aware that I can just outright exclude directories from `File > Settings > Directories` but this is a rather cumbersome way of achieving this as it would mean re-including then excluding sets of directories every time I switch from developing 1 application to another.

Comment: PHPStorm is mainly project oriented, so within the project the scope of the variables is project based. Scopes are intended to limit file appearance/searches and can be applied to inspections as well but does not apply to code-completion. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/changing-the-order-of-scopes.html   You could split the directories into separate projects. e.g. A Symfony app with several bundles. When developing a bundle, testing, maintaining the repo, etc, Open that bundle's project, when working on the Symfony app as a whole, work within the project that contains all bundles.

Comment: In addition one project can contain/attach other projects too. `File > Attach Project` but suffers from the same issue with code-completion.

Comment: Use 2 separate projects as suggested above. Shared code (e.g. PHP classes that is mainly belongs to the first project) can be added to the 2nd project as Additional Content Root (so they are treated as part of the project) or as External Library (via `PHP | Include Path`) so they are referenced mainly for code completion purposes (and not editing).